# Is there a term for "purposely deceptive behavior"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for representing one's self as weak or unintelligent in order to lull an opponent into a false sense of security and thus gain advantage?
I have been using "disingenuous" but that's not correct.

Comment: “**Appear weak when you are strong, and strong when you are weak.**” 
― Sun Tzu, ***The Art of War***

Comment: Related: (Possible Duplicate?) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/195954/the-act-of-baiting-someone-into-incorrectly-calling-bullshit

Comment: Related: [*The Hustler*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054997/).

Answer (score 11):

The term I usually hear is

> **sandbag** *v*, *v tr*
>   To downplay or misrepresent one's ability in a game or activity in order to deceive (someone), especially in gambling: *sandbagged the pool player by playing poorly in the first game when stakes were low.*
>   <sup><sub>[TFDO](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sandbag)</sub></sup>

The etymology is interesting and instructive. From [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sandbag&searchmode=none):

> . . . Meaning "pretend weakness," 1970s perhaps is extended from poker-playing sense of "refrain from raising at the first opportunity in hopes of raising more steeply later" (1940), which perhaps is from *sandbagger* in the sense of "bully or ruffian who uses a sandbag as a weapon to knock his intended victim unconscious" (1882).

I take from this that the sandbag so mentioned must have been a non-obvious weapon that would have taken the victim by surprise.

Answer (score 5):

In the context of gambling, you can use **hustle**:

> To lure less skillful players into competing against oneself at (a gambling game)
>
> ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hustle))

For other contexts, there's the idiom **play dumb**:

> To pretend to be slow-witted or lacking in specific knowledge, usually in order to avoid responsibility or to gain some advantage
>
> ([Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/play_dumb))

TV Tropes also has a whole page on this phenomenon, which it calls [**Obfuscating Stupidity**](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ObfuscatingStupidity).

Comment: Also @LittleEva: *Hustle* really means the opposite. Please read the definitions once again. *Play dumb* works, though.

Comment: This question offers a better definition of hustle then the dictionary.

Comment: @Kris - How does one "lure less skillful players" into competition?

Comment: @Kris: from [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hustle&submit.x=0&submit.y=0); here's a definition that is much more difficult to misread: 4c. *Slang* To misrepresent one's ability in order to deceive someone, especially in gambling.

Comment: @Kris - *per* Peter's AHD reference, i.e., in the game of pool (or, if you'd prefer, billiards) you can consider yourself "hustled" when a shooter of greater skill deceptively convinces you, usually gradually, that they are less skillful then you. "Hustle' nicely encapsulates the OP's request for a single word which means "representing one's self as weak ... in order to lull an opponent into a false sense of security and thus gain advantage."

Comment: **1.** I wonder how a word can have diametrically opposite meanings in the same usage domain. **2.** Yes, AHD does have an entry, though it only says "misrepresent," not "underplay." **3.** It's slang -- I would not offer a slang meaning as an answer when **a.** a formal word alternate exists **b.** the offered word has a regular formal meaning different from the slang usage. (The whole thing may sound like a defense, but the fact is that I had considered all these when commenting.)

Comment: Though I contested the suitability of *hustle* as an answer, I have not down voted.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of terms for the general case of misrepresenting oneself:

- duplicitous
- two-faced
- Janus-faced

And specifically there are:

- modest
- unassuming
- humble
- coy
- self-effacing

The term "false modesty" is of course very applicable, but isn't one word so is barred from conclusion.

Comment: None of them works. Try other words.

Comment: _Janus-faced_ is particularly loathsome, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Janus: Oh, I don't know. My perception of you and your contributions here has forced me to reevaluate that term. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Dishonesty is a stratagem of tricksters, hustlers, and *slimy, double-crossing, no-good swindlers*; who would use ruses, ploys, subterfuge and/or illicit or fraudulent acts, in order to deceive you.

**dishonesty**, noun, dis·hon·es·ty, \–nə-stē\ -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dishonesty)

> lack of honesty : the quality of being untruthful or deceitful
>
> 1:  lack of honesty or integrity :  disposition to defraud or deceive
>
> 2:  a dishonest act :  fraud

---

For reference:

**swindler**: a dishonest person (see scoundrel: [Lando Calrissian](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000031/quotes))

**stratagem**, noun, strat·a·gem \ˈstra-tə-jəm, -ˌjem\ -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stratagem)

> a trick or plan for deceiving an enemy or for achieving a goal
>
> 1.a :  an artifice or trick in war for deceiving and outwitting the enemy
> 1.b :  a cleverly contrived trick or scheme for gaining an end
> 2 :  skill in ruses or trickery

**ruse**, noun \ˈrüs, ˈrüz\ -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruse)

> a trick or act that is used to fool someone; a wily subterfuge

**ploy**, noun \ˈplȯi\ -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ploy)

> a clever trick or plan that is used to get someone to do something or to gain an advantage over someone
>
> 2.a :  a tactic intended to embarrass or frustrate an opponent
> 2.b :  a devised or contrived move :  stratagem

**subterfuge**, noun, sub·ter·fuge \ˈsəb-tər-ˌfyüj\ -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subterfuge) (See stratagem)

**illicit**, adjective, il·lic·it (ˌ)i(l)-ˈli-sət\

> : not allowed by law : unlawful or illegal
>
> : involving activities that are not considered morally acceptable

**fraud**, noun, \ˈfrȯd\ -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraud)

> : the crime of using dishonest methods to take something valuable from another person
>
> : a person who pretends to be what he or she is not in order to trick people
>
> : a copy of something that is meant to look like the real thing in order to trick people

Comment: Disingenuous                                                                                                I think disingenuous is probably as close as I can get with one word.

Comment: @rodb1 It fits the title perfectly but not the content so much. "representing one's self as weak or unintelligent in order to lull an opponent into a false sense of security and thus gain advantage" is all but the definition of *hustle*. Even when falling victim to a (military) feint; you *got hustled*.