# Word for having succeeded but acting as if you've failed

Tags: single-word-requests

My friend just got a new job, but in order to fool others for some time, he acted sad and said he didn't get the job.

Is there a word to describe this behavior?

Comment: He *deceived* others or *tricked* others into thinking he didn't yet get a job.

Comment: What's wrong with liar?

Comment: Close-voters: don't focus on the *job* part. Focus on the *pretending* part.

Comment: You got [suckered](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sucker#sucker__23), my friend.

Comment: @TusharRaj And often expressed as an interjection, *Suckah!*

Comment: @DanBron Why not upvote to encourage retention?

Comment: @Bib, I mean, it's not a *great* question, but I don't think it deserves to be closed. But .. what the heck, I only have 2 votes left to spend today, might as well finish them off.  +1.

Comment: @DanBron I agree about not promoting a mediocre question, but in the interest of fostering good answers, I occasionally adjust my standards.

Comment: @Bib Fair enough.  And your answer *is* quite good.  I spent my last +1 on it (before I even noticed it was yours!).

Comment: @DanBron I didn't mean to suggest that mine was of note. Just wanted to foster the dialog.

Comment: Still waters run deep.

Answer (score 4):

I think **sandbagging** might cover it.

See [my answer to another post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/235435/2303) on a similar topic.

[Quoted here by request]

> The term I usually hear is
>
> > **sandbag** *v*, *v tr*   To downplay or misrepresent one's ability in a game or activity in order to deceive (someone), especially in
> >     gambling: *sandbagged the pool player by playing poorly in the first
> >     game when stakes were low.*
> >     <sup><sub>[TFDO](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sandbag)</sub></sup>
>
> The etymology is interesting and instructive. From
>   [Etymonline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sandbag&searchmode=none):
>
> > . . . Meaning "pretend weakness," 1970s perhaps is extended from poker-playing sense of "refrain from raising at the first opportunity
> >     in hopes of raising more steeply later" (1940), which perhaps is from
> >     *sandbagger* in the sense of "bully or ruffian who uses a sandbag as a weapon to knock his intended victim unconscious" (1882).
>
> I take from this that the sandbag so mentioned must have been a
>   non-obvious weapon that would have taken the victim by surprise.

Comment: Good one! Oh, good one! I'm going to have to wait til tomorrow til I can give you the +1 you so richly deserve. But I'd recommend you copy in the relevant definition & cites so that this answer can stand by itself.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure "sandbagging" is applicable here; it seems to be generally used to deceive with regard to future activity/behavior (e.g. intentionally playing poorly to instill false confidence in competitors, then stepping up when the stakes are higher). OP's friend has *already succeeded* and is just "faking out" his friends.

Comment: As an aside, [this forum](http://www.sndg.org/forum/read.php?2,87943,88097#msg-88057) has an interesting etymology posited for the origins of the term in the sporting/competition sense.

Answer (score 2):

There is the interjection, *[psych](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/psych?rdfrom=Psych)*

> (slang) Indicating that one's preceding statement was false and that one has successfully fooled one's interlocutor. Also sike.

*Wiktionary*

It is sometimes used by the deceiver when he or she reveals the truth (and often to gloat in the deception). More often than not, the deception is of very short duration.

Comment: If we're taking interjections, I have to mention [Bazinga](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/Bazinga)

Answer (score 0):

There are many words to describe this. The best fit is the one you've already used. Your friend **fooled** you. He might actually say those exact words after the act: "I didn't get the job... Fooled you, I did get it."

Quoting OALD notes from [deceive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/deceive):

> Synonyms: **fool, deceive, betray, take in, trick, con**
>
> ***which word?***
>
> Many of these words involve making somebody believe something that is
> not true, but some of them are more disapproving than others. Deceive
> is probably the worst because people typically deceive friends,
> relations and others who know and trust them. People may feel
> cheated/betrayed by somebody in authority who they trusted to look
> after their interests. If somebody takes you in, they may do it by
> acting a part and using words and charm effectively. If somebody
> cheats/fools/tricks/cons you, they may get something from you and make
> you feel stupid. **However, somebody might fool you just as a joke**;
> and to trick somebody is sometimes seen as a clever thing to do, if
> the person being tricked is seen as a bad person who deserves it.
>
> Patterns:
>
> - to cheat/fool/trick/con somebody out of something
> - to cheat/fool/deceive/betray/trick/con somebody into doing something
> - to feel cheated/fooled/deceived/betrayed/tricked/conned
> - to fool/deceive yourself
> - to cheat/trick/con your way into something

Answer (score -1):

There's an idiom for this behavior -- "to shed crocodile tears".  You can also use the verb *weep* instead of *shed*.

From [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shed+crocodile+tears):

> **Shed/weep crocodile tears**:
>
> *to show sadness that is not sincere*
>
> Usage notes: Some stories say that crocodiles cry while they are eating what they have attacked.

Your friend wept crocodile tears =)

Comment: This could be a very interesting answer! Can you include a dictionary (or other authoritative) definition of *crocodile tears* in your answer? Make sure to mention where you found it.

Comment: Crocodile tears is disapproving. It is used when someone fakes sadness in situations that actually call for sadness. What happened here was that he faked the sadness and the situation along with it.

Comment: @TusharRaj Thanks for putting "faking sadness *in situations which call for sadness*" into words. I knew something bugged me about *crocodile tears* but offhand couldn't articulate it (but you can see why I asked for a dictionary definition).

Comment: Dan, I already knew this expression, but added a source. @Tushar Raj -- I disagree.  Kids often shed crocodile tears when they are not actually hurt.

Comment: @icy Sure you knew this expression: that's how you were able to add it as an answer! But the point of answering is to teach it to others, so we often ask for more details, and ideally authoritative references, beyond the simple suggestion itself.

Comment: @icy: So they fall down or get hit or something and start crying loudly; when they're not actually in that much pain. You see my point? They didn't invent the situation. They just faked sadness.