# What word means "pretend to know something to extract information"?

Tags: expressions, verbs, idioms

Is there any phrase or expression that can be used to indicate that someone who does not actually know something (about someone else) is trying to pretend as if they knew it (or talking in such a way that implies they already know it) to maliciously extract information from another person or get that person to admit it?

For example,

> John: Hey, Jimmy, How's the new project?
> Jimmy: What project?

John is pretending to know something that may or may not be true to gather information.

---

**Edit:** The word is not exactly "bluffing". Bluffing is more like lying or bragging.

I heard an exact match in a movie. I cannot remember what the verb was:

> I was trying to _______ on you.

Comment: Bluffing matches your request, and *playing dumb* matches your example of pretending *not to know*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Playing dumb is closer to what I mean but is there something better than that?

Comment: Related (if not duplicates): https://english.stackexchange.com/q/195954/365490 and https://english.stackexchange.com/q/324562/365490

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul: No, I heard something is a movie that was an exact match but can't remember it, couldn't find that in any of the answers in those two links. I don't know the name of the movie :P

Comment: You should have actually said in your question: "Jimmy is pretending NOT to know". That's what you would need in your context. Confusing the way you put it

Comment: @fev: Sorry I made a mistake there, corrected my question

Comment: @fev: No, it was a nice phrase but not `cheating on you`. It was something else. That's why I am struggling so hard to remember that. I am sure about `On you`

Comment: @fev: I know that it may sound unacceptable here but I'm looking for the verb that I have heard and now have forgotten. Was hoping that many people would post answers and I could finally find it in one of them.

Comment: Not an answer but you *might* perhaps find the answer in here https://listverse.com/2019/02/16/10-interrogation-techniques-used-by-the-police/  Technique 7 looks relevant.

Answer (score 3):

That's called ***bluffing***

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bluffing) defines it as:

`to deceive someone by making them think either that you are going to do something when you really have no intention of doing it, or that you have knowledge that you do not really have, or that you are someone else`

e.g.

> - Is he going to jump or is he only bluffing?
> - Tony seems to know a lot about music, but sometimes I think he's only bluffing.
> - She bluffed the doorman into thinking that she was a reporter.

Forced edit:
You could also use ***fake, feign or sham***. For more synonyms, help yourself from [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/fake.html)

As for *pretending **not** to know*, you can choose between:

> - ***play/act the fool***
> - ***play stupid*** (clearly informal)
> - ***act innocent***

Check out the definition of ***play stupid*** in the [Urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=play%20stupid)

```
Pretending to be ignorant to get out of trouble
```

Comment: DVing because your question was not clear and then editing your question is really not fair.

Comment: I gave up... Our OP doesn't remember even the meaning of what he is looking for. I am just wondering: is giving up part of the adapting bit or of dying :0?!?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the person is *dissimulating*. The word may be applied to the hiding of many things including ignorance so is not unique to ignorance. However, if applied to ignorance, it is reasonable to suppose that the motive is for gain such as extracting knowledge or eliciting an admission.

> dissimulate =
>
> to hide under a false appearance
>
> "She smiled to dissimulate her urgency"
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissimulate)

> = to hide your real feelings, character, or intentions
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dissimulate)

The Oxford dictionary adds concealment of thought to the list of hidden things.

> [Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dissimulate)